# Ionic: Make checkbox checked in event handler if specific criteria are met

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, dom-events

I have a form with checkboxes and for certain checkboxes the following applies:

When a checkbox is checked and gets clicked and some statement is true, then the checkbox should not get unchecked, but jump back to checked state.

This is the current html:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked  [innerHTML]="htmlString"></ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox (click)="checkboxClick($event)"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
```

And this is the current .ts:

```
checkboxClick(e){
    var statement = true;

    if(statement){
    e.target.checked = true;
    }
  }
```

Here is a stackblitz showcasing the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tcxd55?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Comment: This is not the right stackblitz

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use (ionChange) instead of (click)

html

```
<ion-checkbox (ionChange)="checkboxClick($event)" checked></ion-checkbox>
```

ts

```
  checkboxClick(e){
    var statement = true;
    if(statement){
      e.checked = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you save my life

Comment: For anyone looking the answer for ionic 5 --> it has been updated as "e.detail.checked"

Answer (score 4):

Below worked for me

HTML:

```
<ion-item>
     <ion-label>Enable Face Plotting (More Processor intensive)</ion-label>
     <ion-checkbox color="danger" checked="{{facePlottingOption}}" (ionChange)="checkboxFacePlotting($event)">
     </ion-checkbox>
 </ion-item>
```

.TS file:

```
export class TabCapturePage {
facePlottingOption: boolean = false;

public checkboxFacePlotting(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.checked) {
      console.log("=========FACE PLOTTING ENABLED");
      this.facePlottingOption = true;
    } else {
      console.log("=========FACE PLOTTING DISABLED");
      this.facePlottingOption = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how the stackblitz relates to your problem, but here I see that you mispelled "target":

```
  if(statement){
    e.target.checked = true;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, updated the stackblitz to the right one. Yes, I did misspell, but changing that does not solve the issue.